# Can I bring poppers on an airplane?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, tsa, drugs

**Poppers as in amyl/isobutyl nitrate.** Officially used as video head cleaner and nail polish remover and room deodorizers. Unofficial use as a sex aid. Can I bring them with me while traveling? Will TSA confiscate them? The bottle is absolutely tiny. Just 10 mL worth.

Comment: Checked-in or hand luggage?

Comment: Given poppers is quite volatile, I wonder if it's flammable? If so, it would be prohibited for this reason. If not, it probably enters the liquids, gels and aerosols regime, i.e. it should be in ≤ 100 ml containers, and all such containers should fit in a 1 l bag if in carry-on, no limit in checked baggage. Also, I'm not sure the legal status of poppers in the US. If it's illegal, it can probably be seized for that reason (though I have no idea if TSA can/will do that). You can ask TSA via the links provided on [this page](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all).

Comment: Yes please consider if popper is legal in the country you land, before any other thought.

Comment: @jcaron flammable liquids are excepted from prohibition if they are ["medicinal [or] toilet articles."](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/175.10#a) Apparently, though, the substances in question here cannot be sold legally for human consumption without a prescription, so they would not be allowed.  If it's labeled as nail polish remover, it might pass muster.

Answer (score 12):

Legally, no.

Under FAA regulations, liquids with a 'flash point' below 60 degrees C/140 degrees F are considered "flammable" and may not generally be carried on a standard passenger aircraft.

Isobutyl nitrite has a flash point of around -23 degrees C/-10 degrees F, which places it not just in the "flammable" range, but well into the "highly flammable" range.

Thus transporting "Poppers" on a plane, in either carry-on or checked luggage, is illegal.

In many parts of the world Isopropyl nitrite is used for "Poppers" instead of Isobutyl nitrite (due to the latter being determined to be a carcinogen). Isopropyl nitrite has a higher flash point, however it is still classified as a flammable liquid, and whilst it is legal to transport it on a commercial aircraft (up to 1 liter per aircraft), it requires proper documentation and approval, so would still generally not be allowed in the form you are considering.

Answer (score -11):

Specific to your reference and tag to the TSA, thus travel within the United States, here's the [Transportation Security Administration](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/party-poppers) view:

> **Party Poppers**
>   **Carry On Bags: No**
>   **Checked Bags: No**
>   [For more prohibited items, please go to the 'What Can I Bring?' page.](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring)
>
> *The final decision rests with the TSA officer on whether an item is allowed through the checkpoint.*

Comment: Maybe something got lost in translation but unless the TSA have a wierd sense of humour, they aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: If you're referring to the 'final decision' (and the TSA is not known for its humour), it's the standard disclaimer on all posted info: basically, don't argue with the TSA inspector you encounter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_popper / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppers (drugs references, possibly NSFW).

Comment: @Giorgio, party poppers are completely unrelated to the poppers in the question.

Comment: OP isn't asking about party poppers, totally different.